# Unable to load memcache.so extension

Tags: memcached, memcache, php-memcached

I built PHP from source with configure command

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.2.8' '--with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd/bin/apxs' '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/' '--with-zlib'
```

I installed php memcache extension :

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache
tar -zxvf memcache-2.2.5.tgz
cd memcache-2.2.5
phpize
./configure --enable-memcache
make
make install
```

I add to my /usr/local/lib/php.in

```
extension=memcache.so
```

Rebooted my apache  and run php-m but php seem doesn't load memcache extension
I followed this solution from this site
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=26554

I added full path

```
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so
```

rebooted apache 
But it didn't load memcache extension ! I google around but the same issue !
How can I load this extension  _ _"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly run your php binary like

```
php -v
```

It should complain that your php.ini wants to load modules that cant be loaded...

If it doesnt complain, run

```
php --ini
```

This should give you the location of your php.ini ( just incase your editing the wrong one :D )

Did this help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is..., at this point: `wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache`
Instead of  `tar -zxvf memcache-2.2.5.tgz`,
you should do `tar -zxvf memcache` (this is the filename from wget).

After you extract the file, you will get the latest version of memcache, at the time I do this, I get the folder **memcache-3.0.8**.

So, the next steps will be:

```
cd memcache-3.0.8 
phpize 
./configure --enable-memcache 
make
make install
```

And finally , dont forget to add this line to your php.ini:

```
extension = memcache.so
```

And restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure memcached is installed in the correct location?
What do you get if you run: `locate memcache.so`

Is memcached installed (the binary)?  Does it require any extra libraries (libmemcache)?

Comment: You should use find, not locate, given that it may not yet be in the locate db.

Comment: The memcached daemon is installed successfull!
and when I locate the memcache extension 
locate memcache.so
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so
/usr/local/src/memcache-2.2.5/.libs/memcache.so
/usr/local/src/memcache-2.2.5/modules/memcache.so

I think the problem is php didn't load the extension !

Answer (score 0):

Add an `extension_dir` directive to tell PHP where to load extensions from and remove the path from the `extension` directive.

```
extension = memcache.so
extension_dir = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
```

Comment: poor me ! It doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped me is to use

```
pecl uninstall memcache
pecl install memcache
```

Another thing (this applies only to rather old php versions though): http://www.hollub.at/phpmanual/ref.memcache.html says:

```
In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with Memcache support by using the --enable-memcache[=DIR] option.
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of your /var/tmp mounted with noexec permission

you can try to recompile memcache using fuenfundachtzig command after temporarily delete /var/tmp symlink and create new /var/tmp folder. (this setting maybe differ from your server)

```
#rm /var/tmp
#mkdir /var/tmp

#pecl install memcache
```

then secure back your temp folder

```
#rm -rf /var/tmp
#ln -s /tmp /var/tmp
```

read more about securing tmp [here](http://blog.hutzoft.com/2010/04/23/securing-tmp-server-hardening/)

and [how to use PECL with tmp mounted with noexec](http://vlexofree.com/blog/2010/06/how-to-use-pecl-with-tmp-mounted-with-noexec/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your PHP compiled, try to remove **extension_dir** from your **php.ini**.

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: this installs "memcache.so" not "memcached.so"*

The problem probably is, that you create a memcache.so with phpize that is for another php-version than you are using. `phpize` always compiles for the latest php version.

install

```
apt install php8.1-dev
```

then you have the version of phpize with

```
phpize8.1 -v
```

download and compile memcache:

```
mkdir memcache-install
cd memcache-install/
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache
mv memcache memcache.tgz
unp memcache.tgz
cd memcache-8.0
phpize8.1
./configure --enable-memcache
make
make install
```

---

Alternatively you can get the `phpize` version by downloading the php-version you want, unpack it, compile and usethe phpize version from there:

check your version:

```
dpkg -l|egrep 'php8.1\s'
```

in my case: 8.1.18

on https://www.php.net/downloads.php download

```
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.18.tar.gz
unp php-8.1.18.tar.gz
cd php-8.1.18/
apt install build-essential autoconf libtool bison re2c pkg-config libxml2-dev
./buildconf
./configure --enable-cli --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite
make -j $(nproc)
```

The compiled binaries will be available in the ./sapi directory:

```
./sapi/cli/phpize -v
```